# translate the billing information in the cart/checkout page

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I want your help please
I spent one week on this issue without any solution
I want to translate the billing information in the cart/checkout page
I dont know how??

I use translate interface but didn't translateِthe first name etc...
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try here http://your_site.com/admin/store/settings/countries/fields